# ListFragment and custom adapter issue (dont show)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I am trying to show elements in a list view using Fragments with custom adapter but it dont works. Any help?

listfragment.xml (it contains listview)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

activity_listview_tickets.xml (this is my custom layout for adapter)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="#F5F5F5"
    android:padding="5dip" >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icono"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:width="48dip"
        android:text="A"
        android:background="#8EC714" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descripcion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icono"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/descripcion"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icono"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment_Tickets.java (my fragment class)

```
public class Fragment_Tickets extends ListFragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private CustomArrayAdapter mAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragment, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
        mAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.list, values);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }


      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // do something with the data

      }

}
```

CustomArrayAdapter.java (my custom adapter class)

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    String[] values;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_listview_tickets);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtIcono;
        TextView txtTitulo;
        TextView txtDescripcion;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        String item = values[position];

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview_tickets, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
            holder.txtDescripcion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
            holder.txtIcono = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icono);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.txtDescripcion.setText(item);
        holder.txtTitulo.setText(item);
        holder.txtIcono.setText("A");

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Anybody can help me and tell what is problem?

Comment: application crashing??

Comment: it was solved. Please, renew the Raghunandan's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 super(context, R.layout.activity_listview_tickets);
```

to

```
 super(context, R.layout.activity_listview_tickets,values);
```

Answer (score 0):

please have a look on CustomArrayAdapter 
have a look on these lines

```
 public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_listview_tickets);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }
```

please write them as follows

```
 public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] values) {
         super(context, R.layout.activity_listview_tickets,values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }
```